# Emacs: Finding function definition in etags

Tags: javascript, node.js, emacs, syntax, jslint

Syntax check in js2-mode is awesome.

But sometimes I just want to define a function named "delete" or "new" even thought that's not a good idea. Js2-mode seems to treat this as an error.

How can I use build-in keywords as function name in js2-mode? I need your help.

================================================

I am sorry for my stupid question...

I'm using etags.

but writing someting like:

```
exports.new = function() {
};
```

seems etags will treat this as the definition of 'exports.new', not 'new'.

```
TAGS
};exports.new248,8614
```

So I'm trying to write something like:

```
function new() {
}
exports.new = new;
```

**How stupid I am !!!**

So my questiong turn back to how to make etags find the definition of 'new', not 'exports.new' ?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

> *"Js2-mode seems to treat this as an error"*

It *is* an error, isn't it?

I really don't understand why you'd want to do it, but the following works:

```
someObject["new"] = function() {
   alert("This is the 'new' function.");
}

someObject["new"]();
```

Assuming `someObject` already exists as an object. Or:

```
var someObject = {
       "new" : function() {},
       "delete" : function() {}
};

someObject["new"]();
someObject["delete"]();
```

In the browser you can say `window["new"] = function() {}`, but you can't call the resulting function with `new()`, you have to say `window["new"]()`.

In node.js I believe the equivalent would be `global["new"] = function() {}`. I don't use node, but I assume this would create a global function called "new", but you wouldn't be able to call it with the `new()` syntax, you'd have to say `global["new"]()`.

I do not recommend doing this.

Comment: `global` is the node.js global variable :)

Comment: Thanks @FlorianMargaine - yes, I just finished googling node around the time you commented. In any case whether in the browser or in node I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: Oh, I really forget that's an error... I am trying to write "function delete() {}; exports.delete = delete;" when using express in node.js. I am sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: I think `exports["delete"] = function() { /*some code*/ };` would do what you want. You'd call it with `exports["delete"]();`. Might be better to use a word like "remove" rather than "delete" so that you don't get the keyword clash.